# Not able to capture SessionDestroyed event in Spring Redis Session + Spring boot environment

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-session

I have a Spring Boot project with Spring Session backed by Redis. I am trying to capture sessionDestroyed event so that I can perform some clean up.

The code to capture the event is as below as per guidance I found elsewhere on Stack Overflow.

```
 @Component
 public class SessionEndedListener implements     ApplicationListener<SessionDestroyedEvent> {


private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(SessionDestroyedEvent event) {

    LOGGER.info("Destroyed session: {}", event.getSessionId()); 

}
```

}

I have set up my Redis Session Configuration like so

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 120)
public class RedisSessionConfig {
}
```

I can see some logs from Spring Redis cleaning up expired sessions every minute as shown below

2016-07-21 11:07:00,026 ==== RedisSessionExpirationPolicy.java ==== thread: pool-4-thread-1 ==== DEBUG   >
org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisSessionExpirationPolicy.cleanExpiredSessions() => [] (line: 107)
    Cleaning up sessions expiring at Thu Jul 21 11:07:00 EDT 2016

But the code that is meant to capture the SessionDestroyedEvent is never called.
What am I missing here?

Please note that I am testing this with a local Redis server where there is no problem in configuring key-space-events as Egx.

When I debugged through the code.

This statement

```
   if(!body.startsWith("spring:session:sessions:")) {
       return;
    }
```

in the class 
org.springframework.session.data.redis.SessionMessageListener returns prematurely before getting a chance to publish the event

because the variable body has a value

> `\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00<spring:session:sessions:2392443d-62a9-4f8c-81f0-c0bb446eb16f`

I am using spring-session 1.0.2.RELEASE. Was there a bug that was fixed?

Comment: This works for me using [Boot sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/samples/boot) from Spring Session project. Are you sure your `ApplicationListener` listens for the correct event type i.e. `org.springframework.session.events.SessionDestroyedEvent` and not perhaps Spring Security's `org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionDestroyedEvent` by accident?

Comment: Does the problem happen in your local environment if you use Spring Session's [Boot sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/samples/boot) and add your `ApplicationListener` to it?

Comment: @VedranPavić, Looks like when I run my app on windows machine the session keys are generated with some extra junk characters  like so "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00<spring:session:sessions:68606df3-be03-472e-84c3-6c9c86d35caa" where as when the application is run on a linux machine, the keys are generated as expected. like so "spring:session:sessions:cc97ebc5-e19c-4a76-8e59-cea67edcb125"

Comment: @VedranPavic  above link is showing 404. can you please help ?

Comment: @Singh123 The current link to that sample should be [this one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/tree/master/spring-session-samples/spring-session-sample-boot-redis).