# Java spring HttpSessionListener

Tags: spring-boot, httpsession, spring-session, servlet-listeners

I wrote my own `SessionExpireListener` that will be invoked when session is deleted. All my sessions are stored in redis. So i am using `@EnableRedisSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 10)` annotation. When i run my server `sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event)` is invoked. After 10 seconds session is deleted from the redis but `sessionDestroyed` event is not invoked.

```
@Component
public class SessionExpireListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionExpireListener.class);

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        LOG.info("Session has been destroyed...");
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LOG.info("Session has been created...");
    }
}
```

No LOG has been displayed in console. sessionDestroyed method is never called.

Comment: Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510187/not-able-to-capture-sessiondestroyed-event-in-spring-redis-session-spring-boot) for some hints in comments. No answer though.

Comment: Also how are you testing the destruction of the session? Are you just deleting in Redis and expecting the event to fire in Spring immediately?

Comment: When session expire i have to invoke sessionDestroyed method and then I can use my redisService to delete session from it.